# Opening new firefox window from puppeteer fails

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, puppeteer

Am I missing something here or is this just not possible anymore? I think I've tried 3 different iterations. This code just timeouts...No luck launching a chrome window either.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-firefox');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    product: 'firefox',
    executablePath: '/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin',
    firefoxUserPrefs: {
      'browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser': false,
      'security.sandbox.content.level': 5
    }
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  // Do something on the page

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `puppeteer-firefox package` is [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-firefox).

When you said, "No luck launching a chrome window either," what code did you use?